# Multiple assignments in CASE statement in VHDL

Tags: case, vhdl, assign

I am still new to VHDL. I need to assign values to multiple signals in CASE statement, something like this :

```
CASE input24 IS
WHEN "00" THEN 
                    output0 <= '1' ;
                    output1 <= '0' ;
                    output2 <= '0' ;
                    output3 <= '0' ;

WHEN "01" THEN 
                    output0 <= '0' ;
                    output1 <= '1' ;
                    output2 <= '0' ;
                    output3 <= '0' ;

WHEN "10" THEN 
                    output0 <= '0' ;
                    output1 <= '0' ;
                    output2 <= '1' ;
                    output3 <= '0' ;

WHEN "11" THEN 
                    output0 <= '0' ;
                    output1 <= '0' ;
                    output2 <= '0' ;
                    output3 <= '1' ;
```

Before trying this I tried assigning the values in a single line like this

```
WHEN "00" => output0 <= '1', output1 <= '0', output2 <= '0', output3 <= '0' ;
```

The second one gave an error

```
found '0' definitions of operator "<=", cannot determine exact 
overloaded matching definition for "<="
```

while the first one a syntax error.

Where am I going wrong ?

Is there a way to assign values to multiple signals for a single case ?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using `CASE` the syntax is `WHEN "00" =>`, thus no use of `THEN`.  The
code is therefore:

```
CASE input24 IS
  WHEN "00" =>
    output0 <= '1' ;
    output1 <= '0' ;
    output2 <= '0' ;
    output3 <= '0' ;
...
```

If `input24` is `std_logic_vector` you must when the case with a `WHEN OTHERS
=>` to handle the remaining encodings of `input24`.  The code is:

```
WHEN OTHERS =>
  output0 <= 'X' ;
  output1 <= 'X' ;
  output2 <= 'X' ;
  output3 <= 'X' ;
```

For writing the assignment in a single like, still use `;` as statement
separator, thus not `,` as shown in the question code, and then just remove the
whitespace.  The code is:

```
WHEN "01" => output0 <= '0'; output1 <= '1'; ...
```

For assign to multiple signals in one statement, the VHDL-2008 supports
aggregate assignment, so if you are using VHDL-2008, you can write:

```
WHEN "10" =>
  (output3, output2, output1, output0) <= std_logic_vector'("0100");
```

For VHDL-2003, a solution may be to create an intermediate `output` signal as
`std_logic_vector`, and then assign to this.  Code can then be:

```
  ...
  signal output : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
begin
  ...
      WHEN "11" =>
        output <= "1000";
  ...
  output0 <= output(0);
  output1 <= output(1);
  output2 <= output(2);
  output3 <= output(3);
```

If the `output` is used, then the exact implementation where the `case` is just
used to set the bit with number given in `input24` can be made with:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

ARCHITECTURE syn OF mdl IS

  SIGNAL output : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);

BEGIN

  PROCESS (input24) IS
  BEGIN
    output <= (OTHERS => '0');
    output(TO_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(input24))) <= '1';
  END PROCESS;

  output0 <= output(0);
  output1 <= output(1);
  output2 <= output(2);
  output3 <= output(3);

END ARCHITECTURE;
```

Otherwise, if the `output` signal is not used, then the `case` can still be
simplified through a default assign as '0' to the outputs, thus with the code:

```
ARCHITECTURE syn OF mdl IS
BEGIN

  PROCESS (input24) IS
  BEGIN
    output0 <= '1' ;
    output1 <= '0' ;
    output2 <= '0' ;
    output3 <= '0' ;
    CASE input24 IS
      WHEN "00" => output0 <= '1' ;
      WHEN "01" => output1 <= '1';
      WHEN "10" => output2 <= '1' ;
      WHEN "11" => output3 <= '1' ;
      WHEN OTHERS => output0 <= 'X'; output1 <= 'X'; output2 <= 'X'; output3 <= 'X';
    END CASE;
  END PROCESS;

END ARCHITECTURE;
```

Comment: @Morten_Zilmer . I was using comma ( , ) to separate them. Thanks. It worked. ( BTW should I remove this question, since I believe its just carelessness on my part ?)

Comment: @Plutonium smuggler: You should not remove the question, since part of the idea with Stack Overflow is to build a question and answer database so others that run into the same problem may find an answer immediately.  Answering the same question multiple times can thereby (hopefully) be avoided.  Once you mark an answer as accepted, the question is likely to attract less attention, thus not wasting time, unless people are curious :-)

Comment: Ok. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is the "then"

```
CASE input24 IS
WHEN "00" => 
                    output0 <= '1' ;
                    output1 <= '0' ;
                    output2 <= '0' ;
                    output3 <= '0' ;

WHEN "01" =>
                    output0 <= '0' ;
                    output1 <= '1' ;
                    output2 <= '0' ;
                    output3 <= '0' ;

WHEN "10" =>
                    output0 <= '0' ;
                    output1 <= '0' ;
                    output2 <= '1' ;
                    output3 <= '0' ;

WHEN "11" =>
                    output0 <= '0' ;
                    output1 <= '0' ;
                    output2 <= '0' ;
                    output3 <= '1' ;
END CASE;
```